# How can I make addView faster in my LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a script that dynamically inserts `RichLinkPreview` into my `LinearLayout`.

**RichLinkPreview:** https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/RichLinkPreview)

It works, but it is very slow. How can I increase its speed?

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/idLayoutNews"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                >
                <io.github.ponnamkarthik.richlinkpreview.RichLinkViewTwitter
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/richLinkView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </io.github.ponnamkarthik.richlinkpreview.RichLinkViewTwitter>


            </LinearLayout>
```

And my Java:

```
   private void createLink(View view){
    LinearLayout layoutNews = view.findViewById(R.id.idLayoutNews);

    layoutNews.removeAllViews();
    String[] lines = stringBuilder.toString().split("\\n");
    for(String s: lines){
        final String[] token = s.split(",");
        RichLinkViewTwitter richLinkView = new RichLinkViewTwitter(mContext);

        richLinkView.setLink(token[1], new ViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(boolean status) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
            }
        });
        layoutNews.addView(richLinkView);
    }
}
```

stringBuilder is a `StringBuilder` that have links.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Why aren't you using recyclerView for this?

Comment: I'm trying but is not easy with this richlinkpreview. But ok, tnks for answer.

Comment: I do not think that problems should arise with this. What is the problem?

Comment: I did a RecycleViewAdapter for my problem, but when I use `RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), listOfLinks);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` I have this error: ` Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview . 
Take a look here